# Rails - Relationship to PORO

Tags: ruby-on-rails, software-design

I have an application where I have table called `land_plots`. Each `land_plot` should have a `water_source` that is either a river or a well.

While the river has fixed salinity, wells generally don't. I therefore need to store the salinity of well water sources as instances but just one value for the river (maybe in the class itself). Therefore, my approach is to create a polymorphic relationship in `land_plot` that can connect to a PORO, `river`, or a another class `well` (that is a regular Rails class).

How can you build a polymorphic relationship to a PORO in Rails?

Comment: I really don't understand the domain here - is this a game? Why would rivers have a fixed salinity? Why would a land plot be limited to one single water source?

Comment: no its not, this is an actual application that Im working on, where if the water source is from the river, the salinity has a fixed value. Otherwise if its from a well, the salinity is variable and should be given

Answer (score 2):

> How can you build a polymorphic relationship to a PORO in Rails?

**You don't.** Assocations are an object oriented abstractration around the relations between your database tables. They exist to make fetching data from other related tables easier. The whole concept is irrelevant when you're talking about a PORO that only exists in the memory of the Rails proccess.

References to a PORO can be stored in memory by using an instance variable.

```
class Foo
  attr_accessor :bar
  def initialize(bar:)
    @bar = bar
  end
end

Foo.new(bar: Bar.new)
```

But then the problem remains how you actually intend to persist the data from one request to the other. You could use novel approaches like serializing the PORO but thats actually significantly worse as you won't be able to query its data in a sane way and it adds a lot of complexity.

Polymorphic assocations are themselves a dirty hack around the fact that the foreign key relations in RDBMS point to a fixed table. Its done by using a string type column with a class name together with a BIGINT column containing the id of the other tables. Rails then uses the `model_name` provided by that class to determine which table to join.

Again if you don't have an *other* table to point to its an irrelevant concept - you can't join a PORO which doesn't even exist in the database.

Comment: Thanks @max for the answer. I edited the question below and replied above. The thing since the salinity is fixed for River, it can be provided as a constant in the River class. Well however needs the value to be stored in the database

Comment: This seems like you're operating on some pretty bad assumptions. Do you think its realistic that you won't have to save anything else related to a river in the future? Is not using a table worth the additional complexity?

Comment: Thinking out loud here. Saving a thousand records all holding the same value or creating this complex solution? What do you think?

Comment: Storing a thousand records in the database is trivial. Fixing the resulting mess from a bad database design isn't.

Comment: mmm, interesting point of view. Thank you so much @max for the answer :D

Comment: In general Rails apps are largely database driven. So it better to plan out your tables and the relations between them based on the domain logic and let that steer how you setup your model classes and assocations and not the other way around.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a `water_sources` table (because you'd like to store information about specific water sources)? If so, you would want to look into single-table inheritance for that table so that you could have a `River` and `Well` class, and use a normal `has_one` Rails association in `LandPlot`. Neither class would be a PORO, but I'm not sure why that's an issue.

If specific water sources don't matter, your `land_plots` table could have a `water_source_type` column storing the string "river" or "well", and your LandPlot class could look like this:

```
class LandPlot < ApplicationRecord
  validates :water_source_type, inclusion: { in: ['river', 'well'] }

  def water_source
    water_source_type == 'river' ? River.new : Well.new
  end
end
```

That's about as much as I can offer without knowing more about your requirements.

Comment: Thanks Mike for the answer

The thing is, for me river has fixed salinity. Therefore I thought it would be redundant to create a database record for each instance. The value salinity can be provided in the class itself. def salinity return 1.0 end for example. This is why the River class is a PORO. Well however has the salinity saved in the database, thus this is a Rails class

Comment: Ah, I see. I hadn't realized that the wells were stored in the database. You could always put a nullable `well_id` on your `land_plots` table and define an association for that, and then in your business logic if there is no well you use the river. Something like: def water_source; well || River.new; end

Answer (score 0):

It strikes me that given that a land_plot can have either a single river source, or a well water_source, and the well has a measure of salinity, there are three alternatives:-

1. Encode the water in some scheme as a string attribute of land_plot: e.g. "river" or "well:12.34", where 12.34 is the salinity, or...
2. Model water_source as a persisted collaborating (referenced 1to1) object incorporating the logic from alternative 1.
3. Simply store the salinity for the land_plot. Include logic that recognizes that a non river specific value must therefore be a well.

Alternative 2 above is sometimes referred to in object modeling as creating a "clutter" or "extension" object.